# call out error: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault:

Tags: callout

I am getting this error when try to make call out to .net server.

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Assemble3DFile'. The characters '<Pro' at offset 0 are not a valid Base64 sequence. faultcode=a:DeserializationFailed faultactor=
```

Anyone here have any idea on this issue. Please guide me.

Comment: Hi Can you past your WSDL file. Refer this link. I hope it will resolve your issue. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213912&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

may be this fails many reasons but just try and see the below :
It would help to see the proxy generated by WSDL->Apex, the response from the WS, or just the schema.

From the error message, you get a response from the WS, but de-serialization fails.

First, you could call the WS from SOAP UI to get a proper image of what you are getting back.

Second, check if you have any numeric properties in the Proxy. Apparently, the deserializer does not map empty strings to 0. To test this, just change the type from Integer/Decimal to String in the generated proxy, and see if you still get the error.

and you can check the below : for reference [How to call an Apex class method from a different apex class? and its related to JSON](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82991/how-to-call-an-apex-class-method-from-a-different-apex-class-and-its-related-to)